# Removing citation from 'list of figures' in DocBook

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, docbook, docbook-xsl

I am writing some document in DocBook and I have there some pics in the document, like this:

```
<figure id="obr3"><title>Logitná transformácia <xref linkend="id8"/></title>           
    <para>
        <mediaobject>
            <imageobject align = "center" >
                <imagedata fileref='obr3.png' format='PNG'/>
            </imageobject>
        </mediaobject>
    </para>                   
</figure>
```

There is nothing strange about it, but as you can see, in the title of the image is **reference**. And my problem is, that in the **list of references** is not just title of current image but also whole its citation, like this:

[image: list of figures [in slovak it is zoznam obrazkov]]

The language is Slovak (`<book lang='sk'>`) as you can see. I want not to display the red area - only the title of the image without citation.

For any help thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use citation instead of xref?

```
<figure id="obr3"><title>Logitná transformácia <citation>8</citation></title>
  <para>
    <mediaobject>
      <imageobject align = "center" >
        <imagedata fileref='obr3.png' format='PNG'/>
      </imageobject>
    </mediaobject>
  </para>             
</figure>
```

and then abbrev in bibliography

```
<bibliography>
  <title>Zoznam použitej literatúry</title>
    <bibliomixed>
      <abbrev>8</abbrev>
      <!--Citation details-->
    </bibliomixed>
```

http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/xref.html

http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/citation.html

http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/abbrev.html